# Uncaught TypeError: Property 'open' of object [object DOMWindow] is not a function

Tags: javascript

This is my code:

```
function loadOffer(id) {
    window.open("http://www.google.com.com","mywindow");
}
```

It's initiated onClick. However I get the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Property 'open' of object [object DOMWindow] is not a function

Any ideas?

Comment: Which browser are you encountering this error in?

Answer (score 7):

You've defined a global variable somewhere called `open` and it's not a function. It's overridden the normal function of `window.open`.

Yet another good reason to namespace our javascripts.

Answer (score 1):

Under normal circumstances, `window.open` *is* a function. So you've probably changed it somewhere else in the code, most likely by defining a variable `open` without a `var` statement.

```
> window.open
function open() { [native code] }
> open = "test"
"test"
> window.open
"test"
```

Answer (score 1):

found this at http://drupal.org/node/1003664

wrap your code in this

```
(function ($) {
  // All your code here
})(jQuery);
```